# Ubuntu. Disable open_basedir and safemode

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, open-basedir, safe-mode

I am running an Ubuntu 10.04 VPS server with PHP 5.3.
I got an error saying that curl does not work with safe mode and open_basedir activated

```
Severity: Warning

Message: curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set

Filename: libraries/Curl.php

Line Number: 213
```

How can I disable safe mode and open_basedir?

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 1):

Just comment out the `open_basedir` line in `php.ini`, you'll probably find it here:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl restart
```

You probably also want to [read about the implications](http://blog.php-security.org/archives/72-Open_basedir-confusion.html) of turning this off.